# Any Windows-based neural network software to help me define parameters and train/test network?

Tags: windows, neural-network

I'm looking for a Windows-based neural network software to help me define parameters (inputs, weights, target values) then train/test the network (specifically backpropagation/sigmoid).

An easy to use C#, java or javascript library would be fine too. I'm looking for a tool to help me demo/learn the backpropagation/training by playing with data.

I've looked everywhere, nothing really caught my attention :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OS-Independent but python based. Otherwise fits what you ask for. See [EpyNN](https://github.com/Synthaze/EpyNN).